# Character's armor piece deforms when posing

Tags: modifiers, pose-mode, shrinkwrap

The muscle brace (L) on my character seems to deform when posing. The blue armor piece on his bicep seems to do the same thing. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thank you blender community.
https://we.tl/t-O8zoRME0yd

Before posing:
[image]

After posing:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that parenting the brace to the bone (with a simple parentage) and using a Shrinkwrap to make it stick to the arm is a good idea, instead I would join the brace to the cloth mesh. Also, the cloth deforms differently than the arm, you need to either correct that in Weight Paint mode, or mask the arm skin with a Mask modifier

Comment: I've solved this issue by clicking the muscle brace and using a 'child of' constraint.